# Untar subfolders from a folder in linux

Tags: linux, directory, tar

I have a directory, `/Landsat_Data/` which contains subdirectories (`Landsat_Data/Site1`, `Landsat_Data/Site2`, etc.). Each subdirectory contains `.tar.gz` files (e.g. `/Landsat_Data/Site2/LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735.tar.gz`, etc.) and each `.tar.gz` file contains tif or xml files like thisL

```
-rw-r--r-- espa/ie  29952 2016-01-07 14:57 LT50930861991021ASA00_sr_snow_qa.tif
```

What I want to do is to untar each tar file into its own sub-subdirectory (e.g. `Landsat_Data/Site2/LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735/`).

So far, I am using this command line while being the Landsat_Data directories:

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir tar -xvzf {} \;
```

However, this command extracts all the tif and xml files into each subdirectory (e.g. `Landsat_Data/Site2`) while I just want to untar the `LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735.tar.gz` to have a sub-sub-directory called `LE70930862008092-SC20160107074735` which contains all the tif and xml files. Any idea how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be in [http://unix.stackexchange.com/](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You might parse the filenames and cd into the directories before running `tar`. You could place a simple shell script into `/folder` like this one:

```
~/folder$ cat extract-in-dir.sh 
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY="${1%/*}"
TARFILE="${1##*/}"

cd $DIRECTORY
tar -xf $TARFILE
```

Then `chmod +x ./extract-in-dir.sh` and run it like this:

`find . -type f -name \*tar -exec ./extract-in-dir.sh {} \;`